# Choosing stepper motor for hand

Tags: stepper-motor

I'm developing a robotic hand, and decided to place motors inside joints (as in picture) and I'm stuck with finding a stepper motor that can fit there. Approximate size of motor body is radius - 10mm, length - 10 mm.

Any suggestions?

[image: Diagram of hand joint with stepper motor]

Comment: Do you have torque and power specifications? Even if you do, this looks like a shopping recommendation request, which is off-topic.

Comment: If you're still in design phase: have you thought about using ball joints, so your hand could do things a human hand can't do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used MicroMo's stepper motors in the past.  You can find their information here:  http://www.micromo.com/products/stepper-motors/stepper-motors-datasheets

However, I don't know if a design process of "make decisions then see what fits" is the best approach.  You should determine the performance you need, then look for components, and base your architectural decision on what you find available.   You may need to relocate the motors and use some kind of mechanical transmission to get the hand performance you're looking for.   It is hard to say with such little required performance information.

Comment: +1 - Form follows function, not the other way around.